# Computer Keeps Losing its Internet Connection (While Still Connected to WiFi)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8

My computer keeps losing its internet connection even though it's still connected to wifi. Usually, when it happens, the websites will remain "loading" so long, sometimes a DNS lookup error results. Sometimes it also says, "your connection was reset."

I thought it was my internet, but while my computer is having internet trouble, the internet works fine on other devices.

I don't know what I should post here, but can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: So your computer still has the wifi symbol in the corner, it just says "Connected, no internet"? (when you click on the symbol)

Comment: Try a TCP/IP Reset, DNS Flush:    Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.   
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt   .
Then: ipconfig /flushdns   Then: restart the computer

Comment: If TCP/IP reset still doesn't work, please update the driver for your wireless network adapter. Sometimes, update the driver may not resolve the Wi-Fi connectivity issues. You would try to reinstall the driver for your wireless network adapter.